# Magento url rewrite management

Tags: magento-1.9

I have confusion in **URL REWRITE Management**. Can you please anyone explain it?

If `url = www.domain.com/all-category/boys-toys/action-toy-figures.html` it redirects to [www.domain.com/action-toy-figures.html](http://www.domain.com/action-toy-figures.html)

I used custom but I can't understand that field section. Can you please explain it to me?

[image]

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: Where i add old url ? where i add new url ? and what is id path? what is redirect?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Type *

Is it a redirect for a product, category or something else.

> ID Path *

Some **unique** identifier (inside the store?). So you can find your redirect)

> Request Path *

The path the customer requests

> Target Path *

The path you want the customer to see

> Redirect

Do you want to make a HTTP redirect (301/302) or redirect internally, which means, no redirect is made, but the controller/router is transfering the request to the other controller

> Description
> no clue, I don't think it is anything important - it is just a description

Hope this answers the question?

Update:
Following this logic, for this example:

- old url `www.domain.com/all-category/boys-toys/action-toy-figures.html`
- i want to redirct to this `www.domain.com/action-toy-figures.html`

You need these settings:

- Request Path: `all-category/boys-toys/action-toy-figures.html`
- Target Path: `action-toy-figures.html`

#### Works for me:

[image]

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Pragma: no-cache
Location: /test.html
Server: Apache/2.4.12 (Ubuntu)
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed, 30 Sep 2015 12:50:33 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection: close
```

Comment: can you please tell me this my old url www.domain.com/all-category/boys-toys/action-toy-figures.html i want to redirct to this www.domain.com/action-toy-figures.html how i achive

Comment: updated questions - maybe you need a starting /

Comment: No it's not redirected

Comment: after click that link it go to http://domain.com/catalogsearch/result/?f=+boys+toys+action+toy+figures+&q=toys+action+toy+figures

Comment: check this url http://kidsdial.com/boys-toys/action-toy-figures.html

Comment: Either this is another url rewrite or something else is redirecting this.

Comment: No i truncate all the value in core_url_rewrite table

Comment: Wherever it comes from, something makes your httpd or magento redirect

Comment: sorry i can't understand

Comment: Something is responding with a redirect on this page. Either it is your apache/nginx (like a .htaccess file or config) or magento is doing it, somewhere in a third party extension or something you coded. SOMETHING is doing it :)

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt help me @ https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/219953/57334